# How do you pet Bubba with a controller?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

When playing Holocure on keyboard you can pet Amelia's dog Bubba by pressing P while standing next to him. However, I'm playing on Steam Deck. Is there a way to pet Bubba when playing with a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just mapped the <kbd>LB</kbd> button to the <kbd>P</kbd> key.

Comment: Can confirm mapping a controller button to `P` with Steam Input worked.